# How to dynamically sort HTML divs in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 4 HTML divs (with nested divs) and sort numbers for each of the divs that can be returned from a function. I'd like to sort the divs based on the sort numbers returned from the function.

What's the best way to do this? I am thinking of arranging the divs in an array like this:

```
$array[$sort_order] = $div;
```

which will translate to

```
$array[1] = "<div class='container'><div class='caption'>One</div><div class='text'>....</div></div>";
$array[2] = "<div class='container'><div class='caption'>Two</div><div class='text'>....</div></div>";
$array[3] = "<div class='container'><div class='caption'>Three</div><div class='text'>....</div></div>";
$array[4] = "<div class='container'><div class='caption'>Four</div><div class='text'>....</div></div>";
```

and then use `ksort()` to sort them before displaying. 
I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there a performance issue? Or there's some reason you prefers other solution than ksort?

Answer (score 1):

i think, u need use ksort before displaying

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid ksort if I have to use loop to display anyways. Which is true in this condition, why dont you put it in loop to display in order:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($array); $index++) {
    echo $array[$index];
}
```